# Two different characterization of "differentiable function"

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In a calculus class we were given the following definition of "differentiable function" (working with 2 variables):

**Definition**: Let $A \in \mathbb{R^2}$, and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$. We say that $f$ is *differentiable* in $(x_0, y_0) \in A$ if the graph of $f$ admits a tanget plane at $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0, y_0))$.

Then the teacher gave us the following equivalent characterization:

**Proposition**: $f$ is differentiable in $(x_0, y_0)$ iff

1) $f$ admits partial derivatives in $(x_0, y_0)$

2) the following holds:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) - A(x-x_0) - B(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}} = 0
$$
where 
$$A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$$
$$B = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$$
i.e. the partial derivatives evaluated in $(x_0,y_0)$

Unluckily, I was not able to find any reference about this.

So here's my questions:

1. **I got it right? Are the two definitions equivalents?**
2. **How to prove that the limit is zero iff the function admits a tangent plane?**

Isn't (2) quite obvious? If a tangent plane at $P$ exists, its equation has to be $$f(x,y) = f(P) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P)(x-x_P) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P)(y-y_P)$$
follow that the numerator of the limit is zero. So what's the point of the denominator? Couldn't one use anything else for the denominator? Am I missing something? **Is (2) noteworthy?**

**EDIT**: As noted below, my "it's obvious from eq. of tangent plane" approach is, in fact, wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition is stated in terms of "the graph of $f$ admits a tangent plane". Did your teacher preceded these words by defining precisely what it means for a graph to admit a tangent plane? If not, then this "definition" was meant as an intuitive description of the concept, not as a definition in mathematical sense.

In the proposition, part 2) is actually the key, and part 1) could even be omitted. Namely, one can state the definition as follows:

A function $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ iff there exists numbers $A$ and $B$ such that 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) - A(x-x_0) - B(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}} = 0$$

Using this definition one can **prove** (and this is a reasonable exercise to do) that both partial derivatives exist and are equal to $A$ and $B$, respectively.

One can also give a geometric interpretation of the limit being zero. The equation $g(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0) + A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0)$ is an equation of a plane. The difference $f(x,y)-g(x,y)$ measures how much the graph of the function deviates from this plane in the vertical direction. The limit being zero means that the vertical deviation at $(x,y)$ is small compared to the horizontal distance between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$: one pictures this as a surface and a plane meeting "at zero angle", that is, being tangent to each other. (But if at this point you'll ask me to **define** what being tangent means, I'll only point you back at the limit: the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are tangent if
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{f(x,y) - g(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}} = 0$$
The limit is the key; geometry is optional but helpful.)

In your post you wrote down the equation of the tangent plane incorrectly, and, which is a more serious mistake, denoted it by the same letter $f$ as the function itself. This is what led you to the erroneous conclusion that "numerator is zero". I avoid this confusion by using the letter $g$ for the function that represents the tangent plane: $z=g(x,y)$ is my notation for the tangent plane.

Comment: Ok, now things seems to be a little more clear! I'll focus on the definition with the limit and the geometric interpretation of that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if there is some linear transformation $A\in {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ so that

$$f(x + h) - f(x) = Ah + o(\|h\|).$$

This abstracts to infinite-dimensional settings.   In standard coördinates, the matrix of the linear transformation is the matrix of partials.

Comment: -1: not an appropriate explanation at this level.

Comment: How did you decide that? In fact, most books I know (Apostol's "Calculus" II, (8.7), page 258, 2nd Ed., Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", def. 9.11 page 212, 3rd Ed., etc.) *define* a differentiable function exactly in this way, i.e. by means of a linear map. This shouldn't be advanced stuff for a student dealing with differentiable functions of several variables.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm not able to understand it completely. The course was a lightweight introdution to 2-variables calculus for CompSci undegrads; and the teacher followed a quite relaxed approach mostly based on ideas from one-variable calculus. I probably should have written that in my question..